# Question is related to Subscription and Discount Coupon

Tags: magento2, module

Following are the pointers

1. Subscription Plan functionality for subscription of certain goodies.
2. After subscription,if customer is purchasing the plan for the first time then coupon code should be generated with thank you /Confirmation mail
3. The  Customer either can use the coupon or if he does not want to use the coupon then he can share the coupon code with other users via mail/invite (Refer a friend functionality ).
4. But the third person can not share the same.

Is it possible to perform this for Magento e-commerce site

Comment: Please rephrase your question